# Passing python list as an function argument

Tags: python

I have the below python code

```
def fir(a,x):
    for i in x:
        h = getx(a,i)
        return h
def getx(a, i):
    print('Hello {} {}'.format(a, i))

print(fir(2,['hi','Helloooooooooooooooo']))
```

o/P gives me as

```
Hello 2 hi
None
```

I dont want None but instead i need

```
Hello 2 Helloooooooooooooooo
```

Why is it showing as None?

Comment: You're returning in the loop, so the loop only runs once.

Comment: `getx` is not returning anything so `h` is set to `None`, which is printed in the console when you call `fir`.

Comment: You are seeing a `None` because `getx` always  returns `None`, and `fir` returns the result of calling `getx`

Comment: Why isn't `hi` in the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `return` out of the loop. Collect all the results of `getx()` in a list and join them in the returned value.

And `getx()` should return the formatted string rather than printing it, so that the caller can print the result itself.

```
def fir(a,x):
    return "\n".join(getx(a, i) for i in x)
def getx(a, i):
    return 'Hello {} {}'.format(a, i)

print(fir(2,['hi','Helloooooooooooooooo']))
```

Comment: it returns only ```Hello 2 Helloooooooooooooooo``` I need both to return without None

Comment: The question says this is what you want to be returned.

Comment: Apologies for that, My intention is to return this value too instead of None. It is miscommunication.

Answer (score 2):

When you return after a loop, make sure that the 'return' code falls outside of the loop. Otherwise, you'll only return the first iteration. See your code updated below:

```
def fir(a,x):
    for i in x:
        h = getx(a,i)
    return h
def getx(a, i):
    print('Hello {} {}'.format(a, i))

print(fir(2,['hi','Helloooooooooooooooo']))
```

Note that the "return h" line is now in line with the for loop, rather than inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You're `return`-ing at the end of the first loop iteration, so the code only sees "hi".